# Google Visualization DataTable Change background color

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatable, google-visualization

everyone!

I have using google visualization datatable to create a simple orgchart but I want to change background color dynamically like the following.

[image]

I have hardcode the row index to change backgroud color. How to get this row index using for loop or other methods? Please help!!!

```
            function OnSuccess_getOrgData(responseData) {

        var orgChartTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        orgChartTable.addColumn('string', 'Division');
        orgChartTable.addColumn('string', 'Department');
        orgChartTable.addColumn('string', 'Section');
        orgChartTable.addColumn('string', 'Team');
        orgChartTable.addColumn('string', 'Leader');

        var response = responseData.d;
        for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
            var row = new Array();
            var divisionResult = response[i].Division;
            var departmentResult = response[i].Department;
            var sectionResult = response[i].Section;
            var teamResult = response[i].Team;
            var leaderResult = response[i].Leader;

            orgChartTable.addRows([
                [divisionResult, '', '', '', ''],
                [departmentResult, divisionResult, '', '', ''],
                [sectionResult, departmentResult, '', '', ''],
                [teamResult, sectionResult, '', '', ''],
                [leaderResult, teamResult, '', '', '']
            ]);

        }

        orgChartTable.setRowProperty(3, 'style', 'background:#A3A2A2 !important;background-image:none');
                orgChartTable.setRowProperty(4, 'style', 'background:#A3A2A2 !important;background-image:none');
        orgChartTable.setRowProperty(8, 'style', 'background:#98FB98 !important;background-image:none');
                orgChartTable.setRowProperty(9, 'style', 'background:#98FB98 !important;background-image:none');
        orgChartTable.setRowProperty(13, 'style', 'background:#E6E6FA !important;background-image:none');
        orgChartTable.setRowProperty(14, 'style', 'background:#E6E6FA !important;background-image:none');
        orgChartTable.setRowProperty(18, 'style', 'background:#f0f0f0 !important;background-image:none');
        orgChartTable.setRowProperty(19, 'style', 'background:#f0f0f0 !important;background-image:none');
        orgChartTable.setRowProperty(23, 'style', 'background:red !important;background-image:none');
        orgChartTable.setRowProperty(24, 'style', 'background:red !important;background-image:none');
        orgChartTable.setRowProperty(28, 'style', 'background:green !important;background-image:none');
        orgChartTable.setRowProperty(29, 'style', 'background:green !important;background-image:none');
        orgChartTable.setRowProperty(33, 'style', 'background:blue !important;background-image:none');
        orgChartTable.setRowProperty(34, 'style', 'background:blue !important;background-image:none');

        var chart = new google.visualization.OrgChart(document.getElementById('orgChartGeneration'));
        chart.draw(orgChartTable, { allowHtml: true });
    }
```

Comment: the `addRows` method returns the row index of the last row added, you could use this to know which row property to set -- it may be easier to use the `addRow` method, which also returns the row index, but only one row at a time...

Comment: orgChartTable.addRows([
                [divisionResult, '', '', '', ''],
                [departmentResult, divisionResult, '', '', ''],
                [sectionResult, departmentResult, '', '', ''],
                [teamResult, sectionResult, '', '', ''],
                [leaderResult, teamResult, '', '', '']
            ]);

I have used addRows method above but I don't know how to return the row index. Could you give an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `addRows` method returns the row index of the last row added

to use the row index returned,
you simply assign that value to a variable

```
var rowIndex = orgChartTable.addRows(...
```

then you can use again when setting the properties

```
orgChartTable.setRowProperty(rowIndex, 'style'...
```

since you're adding multiple rows,
you could assign the rest by reducing the row index

```
orgChartTable.setRowProperty(rowIndex, 'style'...
orgChartTable.setRowProperty(rowIndex - 1, 'style'...
orgChartTable.setRowProperty(rowIndex - 2, 'style'...
orgChartTable.setRowProperty(rowIndex - 3, 'style'...
```